# Systemd stops user manager and kills all user processes

Tags: systemd

I have many podman containers running under a user. The processes running in them are resource intensive at times (CPU and memory).

Until recently we didn't have any problems. But after an unavoidable software update to the one of the programs running inside the containers, the containers keep dying daily all at the same time. I doubled the available RAM which helped temporarily but the problem is back.

I found the following lines in `/var/log/syslog`, that always comes before the shutdown:

```
Jul 24 17:01:26 xxx1 systemd[1]: session-5.scope: Deactivated successfully.
Jul 24 17:01:26 xxx1 systemd[1]: session-5.scope: Consumed 9.924s CPU time.
Jul 24 17:01:36 xxx1 systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
```

There's a CPU usage spike shortly before this because the containers do a scheduled tasks all the same time.

I haven't changed any systemd settings from the original (Ubuntu 22.04LTS). And in the `/etc/systemd/system.conf` the `DefaultCPUAccounting` is set to no.

I suspect that there could be some other limitations causing the shutdown (eg: number of tasks), but I can't find any information in the logs about what prompted the stopping of the user manager.

How can I find the reason for the stop?